# How to permanently remove uhd-Agent from startup / login items with Bluestacks

Tags: macos, bluestacks

Is there any possibility to permanently remove uhd-Agent from login items?

Every time I have used Bluestacks it keeps returning. So I have to delete it manually every time. This has become pretty annoying. I use this great app regularly, but I do not want it to start in the background with every system boot.

Answer (score 1):

Trash

```
BlueStacks.app/Contents/Runtime/uHD-Agent.app
```

by calling from a Terminal:

```
rm -rf /Applications/BlueStacks.app/Contents/Runtime/uHD-Agent.app
```

Then remove it from the login items for the last time.